# Pandas split does not work

Tags: python, pandas, split

It might not be the smartest question ever, but I don't know why the usual split function is returning empty cells in pandas. Here are the couple of things that I have tried:
First:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
df1 = pd.read_pickle('output.p')
try:
    df1['being_remixed'] = df1['file_names'].str.map(lambda x: x.split('by')[1]) # Also tried without str
except:
    df1['being_remixed'] = ""
```

Second:

```
def splitter(z):
    try:
        a = z.map(lambda x: x.split('by')[1])
    except:
        a = ""
    return a
df1['being_remixed'] = df1['file_names'].apply(splitter)
```

And strings on the file_names column look something like this:
"StrandbeestInspiredWalkingMachinebydanowall---*-1043007.jpg" or
"DetailedAlienHead---*-1913632.jpg"
When I split by using "---_-" it works. How could I solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for list of strings with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) for select second value of each list, if one item list it return `NaN`, so [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) is necessary:

```
df1['being_remixed'] = df1['file_names'].str.split('by').str[1].fillna('')
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'file_names':['WalkingMachinebydanowall----1043007.jpg',
                                  'DetailedAlienHead----1913632.jpg']})

print (df1)
                                file_names
0  WalkingMachinebydanowall----1043007.jpg
1         DetailedAlienHead----1913632.jpg

df1['being_remixed'] = df1['file_names'].str.split('by').str[1].fillna('')

print (df1)
                                file_names            being_remixed
0  WalkingMachinebydanowall----1043007.jpg  danowall----1043007.jpg
1         DetailedAlienHead----1913632.jpg
```

Explanation:

```
print (df1['file_names'].str.split('by'))
0    [WalkingMachine, danowall----1043007.jpg]
1           [DetailedAlienHead----1913632.jpg]
Name: file_names, dtype: object

print (df1['file_names'].str.split('by').str[1])
0    danowall----1043007.jpg
1                        NaN
Name: file_names, dtype: object
```